# EmberJS calls to an MVC Web API result in a CORS message when authorization fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, ember.js, cors

I am using EmberJS to communicate with an MVC Web API using Auth0 for authorization. When I have a valid bearer token I can communicate and retrieve data from the Web API just fine. When the token expires the Web API returns an an expected 401 the following message is displayed in the browser console:

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200'**

The ajaxError method of the RESTAdapter is called as expected, but the jqXHR.status field is 0.

```
export default
DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api',
    host: webApiUrl,

    headers: function() {
      return {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken'),
      };
    }.property().volatile(),

  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 401) {
      Ember.Logger.info("Not Authorized");
    }

    Ember.Logger.info("Error " + jqXHR.status + " calling API redirecting to login.");

  }
});
```

Here is a sample of the response returned from the API:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU291cmNlXFBheWNvckRldlxTb3VyY2VcSW50ZWdyYXRpb25cR2VuZXJhbFxNYWluXFBheWNvci5JbnRlZ3JhdGlvbi5PcGVyYXRpb25zXFBheWNvci5JbnRlZ3JhdGlvbi5PcGVyYXRpb25zLkFwaVxhcGlcbG9nZ2luZ0V2ZW50cw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 30 Jan 2015 16:45:35 GMT
Content-Length: 927
```

I have tried XML and plan/text Content-types, but the result is the same.

I don't believe this is an actual CORS issue because this problem only occurs when the API returns an error; otherwise I'm downloading and displaying the data just fine.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and it was a CORS issue.

I'm not sure what backend your api server is but mine is a Rails API and the solution was to move the CORS middleware to the top of the middleware stack

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Rack::Cors' do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

The issue is a bit confusing because before fixing the problem if I made a request using `cURL` I receive the correct response with the right headers etc

```
$ curl -I -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' http://api.example.dev/foo
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Pacu-Media-Type: v1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Rack-CORS: preflight-hit; no-origin
X-Request-Id: def30b49-895f-4581-82ec-87bcfb6c44e5
X-Runtime: 0.010945
Date: Sun, 22 Feb 2015 03:30:35 GMT
Connection: close
```

and the correct error message

```
$ curl -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' http://api.example.dev/foo
{"errors":[{"id":"01ac93be-ea7a-4d8e-b86b-9ea1f4136b11","title":"unauthorized","detail":"The access token is invalid","status":"401"}
```

The problem is that `cURL` is not making a cross site request and therefore CORS isn't needed. When attempting to connect using jQuery the request would fail with the following error in the browser's dev console.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

The response status was 401 but the response body was empty and the jqXHR.status was set to 0.

Again the reason was because my Rails backend CORS middleware needed to be at the top of the rack stack order. In Rails since I am using the Routes Engine as an exceptions app `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` I needed the CORS middleware to load before it in `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions`